# Google Chrome gets really slow on 10+ open tabs

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

For some time already I face a problem with Google Chrome. I really love this browser, but on Windows 7 on a pretty decent machine (i5, 4GB RAM) it gets REALLY slow when I open for instance 10 techcrunch.com pages. Once I do that it becomes virtually difficult to scroll through pages and the general responsiveness of the browser gets down.

And if I open 20+ or 30+ tabs there is a good chance all of them will crash.

Does anyone got an idea? This happens to me on several PCs with Windows 7 64bit.

At 10 tabs there is 600-700MB memory used by Chrome.

Two systems have the issue are both laptops with integrated graphics. One by Intel, the other an nVidia GeForce 310M.

Comment: 32bit or 64bit OS? Having that many tabs is memory intensive.

Comment: Opening all at once or one by one?

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, it's 64bit Windows 7

Comment: @random I go through the start page and open interesting articles in background tabs. After 10-15 such tabs are open the Chrome starts to stop responding

Comment: What sort of video card do you have?

Comment: Hmm. I'm running Chrome with 21 tabs split across 2 windows and while it is using a lot of memory it's usable. What flavour of Windows 7?

Comment: @slhck it's about 600-700 Mb. However there are plenty of RAM available till the 4Gb mark

Comment: @music2myear It's Nvidia GeForce 310M bundled with my Dell notebook. However I see such things on another machine which is a PC with an integrated Intel video card

Comment: It's JavaScript & Flash eating up CPU cycles. I have the same issue. It's happens when you open many tabs out of 1 originating page.

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't been asked: Which version of Google Chrome are you running? ... Do you have any plugins and/or extensions installed? If so, which versions? ... Do you experience the same problems when you use [Google Chrome Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) with default settings?

Comment: Try to disable all extensions and then re-launch your Chrome.

Comment: not necessarily such a wonderful fix but try clicking "stop"(X) it's next to the <- and -> arrows. and is to the left of the address bar. click it when a page is loading, it should stop it loading. others may then get responsive.

Comment: @iglvzx I'm using the latest version of Chrome (16 I think). My plugins are: AdBlock, Xmarks, FireGesures and GMail notifier (latest versions of them). I don't think it's too much

Comment: Now there is stable version 18 available try it and then please post back here to know us the performance on your hand.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any other programs running while trying to open 10 or more tabs in Chrome? Go to task manager and stop any processes that may be taking up memory. If that doesn't work, I found the following on these URLs:

[Chrome Help Forum - open multiple tabs without warning message](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=5ac6a0091316af95&hl=en)

There's something called "TooManyTabs" for Chrome

Suggests using the beta version of Chrome among other things

Comment: Your two links where the same, see [the history](http://superuser.com/revisions/383867/1). Which one of the two was intended to be different? Can you correct that?

Comment: Thanks for catching that, my fault. Here's the other link: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=0de5500a3024d8f0&hl=en While reading further into that forum, it stated that some users could open many tabs at once but certain sites slowed down/froze Chrome

Comment: @ChristopherChipps thanks, the link you provided indeed describes the problem I observer. However the thread doesn't have any useful suggestion. So I'm still looking for an answer here...

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 Professional or Ultimate can run programs in a virtual copy of Windows XP. Try running Chrome in 'Windows XP' mode. I have had the same problem happen to me (Windows 7 Professional 64bit, AMD, 16GB RAM).

Answer (score 0):

This slow down issues may be because of **insufficient memory**. Also **Chrome**'s ***memory management** seems can be another reason.

Some explanation about the issue can be found [here](http://www.filterjoe.com/2010/07/05/memory-hog-chrome-gets-slower-and-slower-a-workaround/) and one of the remarks is :

> When Chrome slows down, close all but one tab then reopen them all

Comment: closing/reopening of tabs doesn't help me

Answer (score 0):

Anton, I open 20-30 tabs at a time, too, so I hear you. Some poorly-coded sites do consume resources like there's no tomorrow; for example, sites that never open new pages when you click their links.

Have you tried **creating a new user profile**? It is step #4 of fixing ["Aw, Snap"](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95669) errors.